# Could we have syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

It happens quite often for mathematical or logical puzzles to be solved creating some programs or scripts, maybe to find the best solution to the task. By the way I actually got a bit disappointed when I found out that, even though I did apply the correct syntax highlighting string to recognize the language, [my post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11033/10248) containing a Python snippet got published without syntax highlighting.

In other Stack Exchange sites, syntax highlighting is enabled by default for code snippets, and users can use the following syntax in their markdown

```
<!-- language: lang-[name] -->
```

to highlight their snippets, replacing `[name]` with the name of the language they use, or with `none` for no highlighting.

---

My suggestion is to make syntax highlighting possible even here (not by default) under the right syntax. **Could we have this feature here on Puzzling SE?**

Comment: Good idea with no downside.

Comment: Definitely agree!  Is there anything we can do to get this to the attention of people with the power to make this change?

Comment: @yjo maybe posting it to Meta SE will bring it to the attention of more people, but I'm not sure it would be very welcome, so I don't exactly know what to do

Comment: Disappointing to see only 50 views in 5 years. Guess this feature won't happen :(